# PouchDB syncing not working

Tags: node.js, proxy, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to setup PouchDB to sync between browser (React + Redux stack) and my databases behind a node proxy (which checks authentication using JWT). here is my proxy code:

```
this.app.all('/database/*', bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}), bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {
  // req.pause();

  const headers = this.auth.proxyRequestDecorator()({headers: {...req.headers}}, req);
  const remoteUrl = req.url.slice(10);
  const opts = Object.assign({
    method: req.method,
    url: `http://${config.get('couchHost')}:${config.get('couchPort')}/${remoteUrl}`,
    ...headers,
  }, req.method !== 'GET' ? {body: JSON.stringify(req.body)} : {});

  mainStory.info('http', `${req.method} ${req.url} -> http://${config.get('couchHost')}:${config.get('couchPort')}/${remoteUrl}`, {
    attach: opts,
    attachLevel: 'trace'
  });

  const remoteReq = request(opts).pipe(res);
});
```

Here is the code I use to sync the database in the browser:

```
function syncDB (dbs: string[], max: number): thunk.ThunkAction<void, Defs.CompactdState, void>  {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const dbName = dbs[0];
    const db = new PouchDB(dbName);
    const remote = getDatabase(dbName);

    db.sync(remote).on('complete', (info) => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_SYNC,
        progress: (max - dbs.length + 1) / max
      });
      db.sync(remote, {live: true}).on('change', (info) => {
        console.log(info);
      }).on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(dbName, err);
      }).on('paused', function (info) {
        console.log(dbName+' pause', info);
      });
      if (dbs.length > 1) {
        return (syncDB(dbs.slice(1), max) as any)(dispatch, getState);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() =>
          dispatch({
            type: END_SYNC
          }), 250);
      }
    });
  }
}
function sync (): thunk.ThunkAction<void, Defs.CompactdState, void>  {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (getState().app.syncing) {
      return;
    }
    const dbs = [ 'artists', 'albums', 'tracks', 'files', 'trackers'];

    (syncDB(dbs, dbs.length) as any)(dispatch, getState);
  }
}
```

But when in the browser I create a new `tracker` document, it doesn't get synceed and if I clear site data, and reload the page the new document doesn't exists (nor in the couchdb ui).

Here is the log :

```
trackers pause undefined
trackers pause undefined
artists CustomPouchError {code: "ETIMEDOUT", status: 0, result: {…}}
albums CustomPouchError {code: "ETIMEDOUT", status: 0, result: {…}}
tracks CustomPouchError {code: "ETIMEDOUT", status: 0, result: {…}}
files CustomPouchError {code: "ETIMEDOUT", status: 0, result: {…}}code: "ETIMEDOUT"result: {ok: false, start_time: Sun Sep 17 2017 19:58:29 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)), docs_read: 0, docs_written: 0, doc_write_failures: 0, …}status: 0__proto__: Error
trackers CustomPouchError {code: "ETIMEDOUT", status: 0, result: {…}}
```

It also blocks the page from reloading when f5 isnpressed until connection times out